# Append form variables to existing query string

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a simple ordering form in the app I'm developing:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'get.index', 'method' => 'get')) }}
                {{ Form::label('order', 'Order by') }}
                {{ Form::select('order' , array('firstname' => 'First Name', 'lastname' => 'Last Name', 'state' => 'State')) }}
                {{ Form::submit('Order results') }}
            {{ Form::close() }}
```

I'd like to append the `order` `GET` variable to be appended to variables in the query string if present, instead of overriding everything.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: You could add the other GET variables as hidden fields to the form to re-send them. About what other variables are we talking about?

Comment: You can also set the action of the form (however you do that in "forms") to include the current query string (`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`) and the browser will append the new values.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Can I add an action alongsite the route option? I'd prefer having a route as an action.

Comment: @lukasgeiter there are a few other possible variables, 7 in total. Most of them are optional though, so it's not only the case that it has to be appended to 7 other variables.

Comment: I don't know, I don't use laravel. I was just suggesting it because that is how you would do it with a regular form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JonathanKuhn mentioned, `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` holds the current query string. You can also retrieve it with `Request::server('QUERY_STRING')`.

Then just use this as an action. You will have to use `url` but inside that you can again make use of the `route()` function for generating the url:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => route('get.index') . '?' . Request::server('QUERY_STRING'), 'method' => 'get')) }}
```

Comment: I don't know laravel, but do you need to include the `?` as part of the concatenated route? Because it won't be included with the query string.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Yep thanks. I kind of had a feeling I was missing something ;)